# Reset ifindex number assignment

Tags: network-interface, udev

I need to reset the ifindex interator when creating new interfaces. I'm using OVS and it requires that an interface index less than 65535. Here is an example command and error. I thought I could do this by reloading udev but that didn't work or I didn't do it correctly.

```
# ovs-ofctl add-flow vbr14 in_port=230087,dl_dst=01:80:c2:00:00:0e,dl_type=0x88cc,actions=output:230054

2018-05-16T01:15:02Z|00001|ofp_util|WARN|port 230087 is outside the supported range 0 through ffff or 0xffffff00 through 0xffffffff
ovs-ofctl: 230087: port value out of range for in_port
```

Comment: Um, you apparently typed a command that includes `in_port=230087`, and you got an error message that said that `230087` was out of range. Why do you believe that you have to “reset” something to fix this?

Comment: The OVS error. It only supports ifindex values up to ffff (65535)

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying. Did you type the `in_port=230087` command or didn’t you?  If you did, stop typing `in_port=230087` and type something like `in_port=2087` instead.  If you aren’t typing `in_port=230087`, what are you saying?

Comment: I don't pick that value... When an interface is created it gets a value. This is in the file /sys/class/net/INT_NAME/ifindex

Comment: I have legitimately created over 200k interfaces, not simultaneously but the ifindex value doesn't reset.